# $\exists\ n \gt 34131$ with more than $7$ odd divisors $d_i \gt 1$ such as when $d_i+1$ are accumulated in increasing order to $1$ the sums are prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

In the same style as a [previous test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599295/can-exist-an-even-number-greater-than-36-with-more-even-divisors-than-36-al), I did a little test today looking for all the numbers such as the odd divisors, ordered in increasing order excluding $1$, when they are accumulated one by one to $1$ the resulting sums are always prime numbers:

The first elements of the sequence are $\{3,5,6,10,11,12,17...\}$, it is not included at OEIS:

> $n=3$, odd divisors not including $1$ are: $\{3\}$ and $1+(3+1)=5 \in \Bbb P$.
>
> $n=5$, odd divisors not including $1$ are: $\{5\}$ and $1+(5+1)=7 \in \Bbb P$.
>
> $n=6$, odd divisors not including $1$ are: $\{3\}$ and $1+(3+1)=5 \in \Bbb P$.

For instance $n=39$ has $3$ divisors:

> $n=39$, odd divisors not including $1$ are: $\{3,13,39\}$ and $1+(3+1)=5 \in \Bbb P$, $5+(13+1)=19 \in \Bbb P$, $19+(39+1)=59 \in \Bbb P$.

I tried to look for the one with the longest list of divisors, but it seems that the longest possible length is $7$ elements, for $n=34131$, at least up to $n=1.6 \cdot 10^9$ and in all cases $n$ is an odd number (thanks to @Peter for the feedback in the comments!):

> $n=34131$, odd divisors not including $1$ are: $\{3,31,93,367,1101,11377,34131\}$ and $1+(3+1)=5 \in \Bbb P$, $5+(31+1)=37 \in \Bbb P$, $37+(93+1)=131 \in \Bbb P$, $131+(367+1)=499\in \Bbb P$, $499+(1101+1)=1601 \in \Bbb P$, $1601+(11377+1)=12979\in \Bbb P$, $12979+(34131+1)=47111 \in \Bbb P$.

So far heuristically I can see that the list of $n$'s includes some $p$ primes and $2p$.

I would like to ask the following question:

> Why does it seem impossible to find a $n \gt 34131$ such as all the odd divisors comply with the property and the length of the list of those divisors is longer? Is there a theoretical reason behind? Is there a counterexample? (maybe a very big number due to the conditions of the property?)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: There is no example upto $n=4\times 10^8$, but I think there should be one.

Comment: @Peter thanks for the feedback! that is quite amazing, it seems significant because $34131$ is relatively small in comparison with the whole interval you tested... but as you said, it could be possible a counterexample over $4$ x $10^8$.

Comment: @Peter I could be wrong but $8697$ seems to fail for the last value, so it does not comply: $1+3+1=5$ ok, $5+13+1=19$ ok, $19+39+1=59$ ok, $59+223+1= 283$ ok, $283+669+1=953$ ok, $953+2899+1=3853$ ok, but the last one would be $3853+8697+1=12551$ and that number is not prime. So I think still $34131$ would still be the smallest one.

Comment: You are right. I did not consider to check the last value. But the claim that there is no example upto $4\times 10^8$ remains true. And I knew that the $1$ does not count. $34131$ is indeed the smallest example.

Comment: We can assume that $n$ is odd.

Comment: I extended the search to $1,6\times 10^9$ without success.